# Microsoft Access data macro associated with After Delete Event

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I have a lab question that required Microsoft Access to do. Since I can't afford Microsoft Access to complete the assignment I have to instead use my best knowledge regarding the subject.

I have to create a data macro that is associated with an After Delete event. The macro needs to increment a field value by -1. In theory there are two tables talking here. The Reservation table and the Customer table which are linked via a Foreign Key called CustomerID from the Customer Table. Since I cannot test my solution in my own environment I was hoping to get some input as to whether I might be on the right track or not, in solving this question. If not, some guidance on matter of fact would be greatly appreciated and helpful.

Thank you

-- Here is my T-SQL data macro

```
IF COUNT([Reservation].[CustomerID]) > 0 THEN
    Look up a record in         Customer
        Where Condition      =[Reservation].[CustomerID] = [Customer].[CustomerID]

    Look up a record in        Customer
        Where Condition    =COUNT([Reservation].[CustomerID] != [Customer].[PreviousTrip]

        EditRecord
            SetLocalVar

                Name         Temp
                Expression     =Customer.PreviousTrip
            SetField
                Name        Customer.PreviousTrip
                Expression     =Temp - 1
            End EditRecord

End If
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Why can't you test your makro? Why do you think you need that makro? If you store the customer-trips in a table, you can simply lookup the prevoius one with a query if needed.

Comment: And increment by -1 is called decrement ;)

Comment: _Right track or not?_ I would say _no track_ as T-SQL doesn't run in Access. So, download a trial of Access and start there. You can easily manage before it runs out.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of just updating a single field I am updating all of the field attributes for Customer.PreviousTrip.
I only want to know if I have the fundemental solution here. The logic for incrementing or decrementing my attributes for field PreviousTrip will be next. For right now I just want to know if I have understood enough of my mistakes from earlier.

SELECT Customer.CustomerID, PreviousTrip, COUNT(Reservation.CustomerID) AS Temp
FROM Customer, Reservation
CASE
WHEN Customer.PreviousTrip != Temp
THEN
UPDATE Customer
SET Customer.PreviousTrip = Temp
WHERE Reservation.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
END
;

or could I say?

SELECT ReservationID, Customer.PreviousTrip
FROM Reservation, Customer
CASE
IF COUNT(Reservation.ReservationID) != SUM(Customer.PreviousTrip)
THEN
UPDATE Customer
SET Customer.PreviousTrip = COUNT(Reservation.CustomerID)
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = Reservation.CustomerID
END
;

Thank you

Comment: [Why Should You Not to Use Old Style JOIN?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/08/sql-server-why-should-you-not-to-use-old-style-join/)